# How to use the multiple column to select in oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_pop1
AS
CUST_ID varchar2(100);
ROUTERNAME_N VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
SELECT TRAFFIC_CUST_ID INTO CUST_ID, ROUTERNAME INTO ROUTERNAME_N
FROM INTERFACE_ATTLAS
WHERE rownum < 2;
IF CUST_ID LIKE 'RNS%' THEN
dbms_output.put_line(CUST_ID);
dbms_output.put_line(ROUTERNAME_N);
ELSE
dbms_output.put_line('It doesn''t Contain');
END IF;
END;
```

/* Here I am trying to fetch the multiple column and display , But I am getting following error  :Errors for PROCEDURE GET_POP1:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
6/3      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
6/51     PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
SQL> show errors  procedure get_pop1;
Errors for PROCEDURE GET_POP1:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
7/3      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
7/51     PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
16/3     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF"
SQL> show errors  procedure get_pop1;
Errors for PROCEDURE GET_POP1:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
6/3      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
6/51     PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
SQL> show errors  procedure get_pop1;
Errors for PROCEDURE GET_POP1:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
6/3      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
6/51     PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
SQL>
```

Comment: What is the question ? Where do you think your problem come from ? What have you tried to correct it so far ?

Comment: I am trying to fetch multiple column from select query, and compiled it, at that time these error error coming

Comment: The code does not really make sense. You retrieve an arbitrary (aka "random") row from the table and the check if the CUST_ID starts with `RNS`. What is the purpose of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**As documented in the manual**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS218) `into` is only used once:

```
SELECT TRAFFIC_CUST_ID, ROUTERNAME
  into CUST_ID, ROUTERNAME_N
FROM INTERFACE_ATTLAS
WHERE rownum < 2;
```

Comment: I suppose `into INTO` is a typo?